# Pandas: Constructing a cross table from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I got a DataFrame generated from a CSV database with a list of districts in Buenos Aires Province (Argentina). The CSV has columns like population and surface of all of these districts. Also, it contains two columns with categorical variables. The first of these one is called "REGION", and indicates if the district is located in the north or in the south of the province. The second one, is called "PERTENENCIA" (Belonging), and indicates if the district belongs to the metropolitan area of Buenos Aires City (Greater Buenos Aires, GBA), or it's in the interior of the province (outside GBA). So then, it can adopt the values "GBA" or "INTERIOR", respectively. Since the metropolitan area of Buenos Aires is located at the north of the province, every district which belongs to the GBA it's also categorized as north (we have no districts categorized in south and also in GBA)

So then, my table looks like this ("Municipio" is the district, "Poblacion" is population, and "Superficie" is surface):

```
    MUNICIPIO     REGION     PERTENENCIA     POBLACION   SUPERFICIE
0   ALSINA          SUR       INTERIOR          ...         ...
1   ADOLFO GONZ.    SUR       INTERIOR          ...         ...
2   ALBERTI        NORTE      INTERIOR          ...         ... 
3   ALT. BROWN      SUR         GBA             ...         ...
4   ARRECIFES      NORTE      INTERIOR          ...         ...
5   AVELLANEDA     NORTE        GBA             ...         ...
...
140 ZARATE         NORTE      INTERIOR          ...         ...
```

The issue is this one: I need to study jointly the frequency of those districts, both by region and belonging. I'm making a stacked bar chart just for that purpose, and also a nested pie chart.

For that, I'd like to generate a cross-table with the total amount of districts in those categories, something like this:

```
      GBA INTERIOR TOTAL
NORTE  33     41     74
SUR     0     67     67
TOTAL  33    108    141
```

I have now something like this to calculate these values manually:

```
cant_mun_gba=municipios['PERTENENCIA'].value_counts()['GBA']
cant_mun_interior=municipios['PERTENENCIA'].value_counts()['INTERIOR']

cant_mun_norte=municipios['REGION'].value_counts()['NORTE']
cant_mun_sur=municipios['REGION'].value_counts()['SUR']

cant_mun_norte_interior = cant_mun_norte - cant_mun_gba
cant_mun_norte_gba = cant_mun_gba
cant_mun_sur_interior=cant_mun_sur
cant_mun_sur_gba=0
```

Although this works, it's pretty ugly, and also I'd like to have the cross-table, just for displaying it.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pd.crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(municipios['REGION'], municipios['PERTENENCIA'])
```